# InstallShield Extension Condition DLL in .NET

Tags: installshield

I'm writing a Suite Installer in InstallShield 2012 Spring Premiere and am including an Extension Condition DLL in the project. I have a .NET version of the library that is included with my application and I'd like to add on the Extension Condition APIs to it so that I don't have to write a C++ version of the exact same code.

Has anyone done this before? Is there a sample project I can look at? KB Article reference?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

may be you can make your .Net Dll COM Visible. Look at this article. 
http://jumbloid.blogspot.ca/2009/12/making-net-dll-com-visible.html